# TBitmap LoadFromResourceName is not working

Tags: c++builder, tbitmap

I am using C++Builder. I have 70 small bitmap images in a .res file.

My code using MyBitMap->LoadFromResourceID works and loads the bitmap from the .res file.

```
    TBitmap *MyBitMap = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    MyBitMap->LoadFromResourceID( (int)HInstance, 2 );
    delete MyBitMap;
    MyBitMap=NULL;
```

The code below using MyBitMap->LoadFromResourceName gives the error "raised exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource cp2.bmp not found'."

```
    TBitmap *MyBitMap = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    const UnicodeString MyName = "cp2.bmp";
    MyBitMap->LoadFromResourceName((int)HInstance, MyName );// Error Here
    delete MyBitMap;
    MyBitMap=NULL;
```

Here is the top of my .rc file. I have setup all the bitmaps with an ID number and the file name. Loading using the name does not work. Can you show how to use LoadFromResourceName. Thanks.

```
99 BITMAP "cp0.bmp"
1 BITMAP "cp1.bmp"
2 BITMAP "cp2.bmp"
3 BITMAP "cp3.bmp"
4 BITMAP "cp4.bmp"
5 BITMAP "cp5.bmp"
6 BITMAP "cp6.bmp"
7 BITMAP "cp7.bmp"
8 BITMAP "cp8.bmp"
9 BITMAP "cp9.bmp"
```

I tried every solution I could find in Google, the Embarcadero Wiki Docs and on ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoadFromResourceName()` is failing because none of your image resources are named `cp2.bmp`.  That is just the filename that the resource compiler pulls image data from while compiling the `.res` file.  The actual IDs in your `.res` are 99, 1, 2, 3, etc.  That is why `LoadFromResourceID()` works.

Resources can't have both numeric IDs and non-numeric names, they can have one or the other.

If you want to assign names to your resources, it should look more like this  instead:

```rc
CP0 BITMAP "cp0.bmp"
CP1 BITMAP "cp1.bmp"
CP2 BITMAP "cp2.bmp"
CP3 BITMAP "cp3.bmp"
CP4 BITMAP "cp4.bmp"
CP5 BITMAP "cp5.bmp"
CP6 BITMAP "cp6.bmp"
CP7 BITMAP "cp7.bmp"
CP8 BITMAP "cp8.bmp"
CP9 BITMAP "cp9.bmp"
```

```cpp
TBitmap *MyBitMap = new Graphics::TBitmap();
const UnicodeString MyName = _D("CP2");
MyBitMap->LoadFromResourceName((NativeUInt)HInstance, MyName);
delete MyBitMap;
MyBitMap = NULL;
```

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[About Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files)

[Resource-Definition Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-definition-statements)

[BITMAP resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/bitmap-resource)